# How to set ViewBag in IActionFilter MVC6?

Tags: overriding, viewbag

```
public class MAttribute : IActionFilter
{

public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext actionContext)
    {
        string searchData = "";
        actionContext.Controller.ViewBag.SearchItem = searchData;
        //object not included in the definition
    }

}
```

when  i  override `IActionFilter`  , it prompt 'object not included in the definition', so How to set ViewBag in `IActionFilter MVC6` ?

Comment: Minor clarification: You don't "override" an interface; you "implement" it. (As opposed to inheriting from a base class, there is no existing implementation there to override.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inheriting from `ActionFilterAttribute`
And I think the method signature you want is `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext)`

For more info, see: http://www.strathweb.com/2015/06/action-filters-service-filters-type-filters-asp-net-5-mvc-6/

Edit: You'll probably also want to add `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;` at the top if you haven't already.

Comment: thanks, i try to  override OnResultExecuting. and it work .

Comment: `public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
        {
            var controller = context.Controller as Controller;
            controller.ViewBag.Text = "test";
            base.OnResultExecuting(context);
       }`